# Maximality of an ideal implies co-maximality

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be ideals of a ring $R$.

Let $A$ or $B$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

I need to show that $A$ and $B$ are co-maximal ideals i.e. $A+B = R$.

WLOG, let $A$ be a maximal ideal of $R$.

Now I know that $A+B$  is an ideal of $R$ containing both $A$ and $B$.

So $A \subset A+B  \subset R$.

Since $A$ is a maximal ideal, therefore $A$ = $A+B$ or $A+B = R$.

How can I show that former  can't be true?

Comment: Did you mean to say, let $A$ **and** $B$ be **distinct** maximal ideals of $R$?

Comment: A=A+B is equivalent to..., a condition you just missed.

Comment: What the comments are getting at laterally is that your problem, as stated right now, is wrong. Maybe check the wording to see if it should’ve been like Kenny W says.